# d3.js axes for time intervals (ages) spanning days, months, years

Tags: datetime, d3.js, momentjs, data-visualization

I have a data set that contains different ages. Age column has data like this:
1 day, 1 week, 1 year, 2 days, 2 months, 3 years, 20 years, etc.

I want to show it in D3.js displaying as multi line chart, age on x axes and on Y- how many times this age occurs in data set.

But is it possible to visualise it as it is? Or i would need to convert this data to one format, eg. only days( months/ years)?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You'd probably want a log scale, which d3 provides. And, yes, convert to a common format. But your log scale axis could be smart about representing the time period, or you could make the tick labels manually like you listed.

[Moment.js durations](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) would make it easier. For instance:

```
let ages = [ 1, 'day'], [1, 'week'], [1, 'year'], [2, 'days'], [2, 'months']]
let durations = ages.map(([n, unit]) => moment.duration(n, unit))
let asDays = durations.map(d => d.asDays()) // [1, 7, 365, 2, 61]
```

Combining that with a d3 log axis [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7621155), I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sigfried/6f8gybx1/50/) that shows how to get from your data to a common unit, but then show human-friendly labels on the axis.

Comment: I never heard about log scale! thank you so much! it will be the best option i guess. originally i wanted to do chart based on this one https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955  but then realised it is not going to work. Will look for similar example with log scale!

Comment: A couple links that might be helpful: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_scale. https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/exponential-and-logarithmic-functions/logarithmic-scale/v/logarithmic-scale. https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7621155. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385737/group-log-file-data-by-time-interval-in-d3.

Comment: Also, you might want to use something like moment.js for formatting the time intervals for the tick labels, and have the data coded as number of days or something like that. Moment.js definitely knows how to turn time intervals (probably in milliseconds) into nice text labels.

Comment: thank you for your help! i will check all the links and moment.js! havent heard of that either!